# composer now throwing an error after attempting to setup IronMQ

Tags: composer-php, ironmq

I ran 
`composer self-update`

then I added this in my composer.json

```
"iron-io/iron_mq": "*"
```

the ran

```
composer update
```

and

```
composer install
```

But now no matter what I do I'm getting this error

```
C:\Project>composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

Fatal error: Class 'IronCore' not found in C:\Project\vendor\iron-io\iron_mq\IronMQ.class.php on line 118
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
```

Did something get corrupted what's going on? I tried to remove the line in composer but the error is stuck there now!

Comment: Could you provide example composer.json? Can't reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

Uh... No idea what just happened.

Try to:

1. declare exact version: (latest for iron_mq: 1.4.5)
2. add line with iron_core dependency (should work without it though):

> "iron-io/iron_core": "0.1.5"

EDIT:

Please test latest iron_mq version (1.4.6)

Comment: thousandofthem, I can't run anymore composer commands I tried adding iron_core as suggested but that error kills everything everytime, how can I clear that packages without using the command line? Where does it extract and where is it listed so I can remove the references?

Comment: I just deleted my entire vendor directory and re-ran composer install without iron mq, everything works again, as soon as I add iron_mq or iron_core the error creeps back in again, compatibility issues with windows perhaps?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Works each time I redeclare the version number (switch between 1.4.5 and 1.4.4 each time the error occurs). There's also a (closed) issue on Github on this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1106

Comment: Added quickfix in iron_mq version 1.4.6. now it'll not throw any error in case of missing IronCore class.